# Google Spreadsheets API Not Giving a Response

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm using Google's Drive and Spreadsheet API together to try and edit some spreadsheets in Google drive. I'm trying to get a list of my worksheets currently. I'm working with their Ruby client, and am trying to grab the list of worksheets in the following way:

```
response = client.execute(
    :http_method => :get,
    :uri => "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1MBP9Q9Q-9ZgLoYnY8ExS-EcxHLESI_vcK4J91ngp6-Q/private/full"
)
```

Client is a fully authenticated Google::APIClient object, and it has all permissions and scopes to access what it needs to access. However, when I try to print `response.body` to the console, it comes out blank, meaning I never captured the response.

However, when I try doing the same stuff in Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground, sending a GET request to that endpoint, it returns all the data I'm hoping to capture in the `response` variable. Any ideas why this is happening? I don't know why it would be returning nothing in my console, but in the OAuth 2.0 playground, it gives the data I need.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the full response object, not just `response.body`. It might be under a different method, or you might find a more specific error.